# Evaluating right hand limit for a function

Tags: limits, logarithms

I want to prove the following right-hand limit (one sided limit) using $\epsilon-\delta$ definition;

$\lim_{u\to 0^+} {u^{s_0} f(-ln u)} = 0$

where $f$ is a function from $R \to R$ and $s_0$ is a positive real number.

Can anybody assist me in it.

I searched out its proof or any hint, in this forum, but could not find it.

Comment: It may be an easy question, but I have not any clue about its proof. Can anybody run me with some proof steps...

Comment: What is $f$ ? ..

Comment: $f$ is any function from $R \to R$. Let me edit question please.

Comment: The existence of the limit depends on $f$ and $s_0$... With these information, nothing can be said.

Comment: I have added the information about $s_0$ i the question.

Comment: If $ f(x)=1$ for all $x$ ,the limit is $ 0$. If $ f(x)=\exp (s x),$ the limit is $1$. In general there will often be no limit.